# Insertion Sort using an array list java

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, insertion-sort

I have no idea how to get my new list to print

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

  public class InsertionSort {
      public static int insertion(List<String> sorted) {

    sorted = new ArrayList<String>();
    String list[] = {"Banana","Pear","Apple","Peach","Orange"};

    String temp="";
    int f = list.length;
    for(int i=0;i<f;i++){
      for(int j=i+1;j<f;j++){
        if(list[i].compareToIgnoreCase(list[j])>0){
          temp = list[i];
          list[i]=list[j];
          list[j]=temp;
         }
      }
    }
    System.out.print(list);
    return list[].InsertionSort;
```

I keep getting this error for the line above
1 error found:
InsertionSort.java  [line: 22]
Error: class expected

```
      }
  }
```

Comment: return list[].InsertionSort; is not a valid Java statement....

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), it will look like so :

```
    for ( String i : list){
       System.out.print(i);
    }
```

You can't print out the array like you did here:

```
  System.out.print(list); // DOES NOT WORK
```

Because println takes in a variety of parameters, but not an array( although one version takes an array of chars ). See [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29)

But if you said,...

```
  System.out.print(list[1]);
```

for example, it would compile..

You have other issues to fix though..

Answer (score 1):

```
return list[].InsertionSort //what's mean is code?
```

if you want to print list you can like this:

```
for(String str:list) //this list is list<String>
{
System.out.println(str);
}
```